# Plotting "blank" and "non numeric data" along with numeric data in Python using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data set which contains some blank or '\N' characters in my SQL server which happens to be my Y axis. My x axis is the date stamp.

I wanted to plot them using matplotlib but getting an error as "could not convert string to float: '\N'"

```
enter code here
QueryTest = "SELECT dest FROM dbo.test order by TIME ASC"
for rows in cur.execute(QueryTest):
    yaxis1.append(rows)
```

This gives me an error as "could not convert string to float: '\N'"

Then I tried to replace the "\N" from my input data with ""

```
for rows in cur.execute(QueryTest):
    startingInfo = str(rows).replace('(','').replace(')','').replace("\\\\N",'').replace('NULL','').replace('\\u','').replace(',',''))
    yaxis1.append(startingInfo)

mix = np.array(yaxis1,dtype='|S4')    
yfor = mix.astype(np.float)
```

This gives me ar error as "could not convert string to float:"

My input data is like this

dest
3.59
0.78
10.2
6.8
3.13
0
0
2.78
0
0.41
2.78
4.55
2.78
\N
0
0
10.84
0.48
0

Comment: So where on the coordinate system would you plot the point `(1,\N)` and `(1," ")`? It's hard to think of a situation where mixing numerical and non-numerical data on one common axis makes sense.

Comment: Actually I would like it to be blank in fact I just replaced the \N with a "NaN" and it seems working now. Actually my data from the network sometimes is not reported so it becomes \N